# Handle positional parameter in a function using if statements in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a function to build the function for `Set-AzServiceBusTopic` by making it more is smarter using if statments weaher to add the postional parmater.

Function

```
function Update-ServiceBusTopic {
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/set-azservicebustopic?view=azps-9.7.1

    param (
        [bool]$AsJob,
        [int]$AutoDeleteOnIdle,
        [int]$DefaultMessageTimeToLive,
        [int]$DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow,
        [bool]$EnableBatchedOperations,
        [bool]$EnableExpress,
        [bool]$EnablePartitioning,
        [int]$MaxSizeInMegabytes,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$TopicName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$NamespaceName,
        [bool]$NoWait,
        [string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [string]$Status,
        [string]$SubscriptionId,
        [bool]$SupportOrdering
    )
    #Create String for $true & $false items
    if ($EnableBatchedOperations -eq $true) {
        $EnableBatchedOperationsValue = '-EnableBatchedOperations'

    }
    else {
        $null = $EnableBatchedOperationsValue
    }
    if ($EnableExpress -eq $true) {
        $EnableExpressValue = '-EnableExpress'
    }
    else {
        $null = $EnableExpressValue
    }
    if ($SupportOrdering -eq $true) {
        $SupportOrderingValue = '-SupportOrdering'
    }
    else {
        $null = $SupportOrderingValue
    }

    try {
        Set-AzServiceBusTopic -TopicName $TopicName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -AutoDeleteOnIdle (New-TimeSpan -Minutes $AutoDeleteOnIdle) -DefaultMessageTimeToLive (New-TimeSpan -Days $DefaultMessageTimeToLive) -DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow (New-TimeSpan -Minutes $DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow) $EnableBatchedOperationsValue $EnableExpressValue $SupportOrderingValue

    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Something threw an exception"
        Write-Output $_
        Write-output $Error[0]
    }
}
```

The code is calling it

```
[bool]$AsJob = $false,
[int]$AutoDeleteOnIdle = 5,
[int]$DefaultMessageTimeToLive = 14,
[int]$DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow = 10,
[bool]$EnableBatchedOperations = $true,
[bool]$EnableExpress = $false,
[bool]$EnablePartitioning = $false,
[Int]$MaxSizeInMegabytes = 1024,
#[Parameter(Mandatory)]
#[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$TopicName = "HelloWorld",
#[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
#[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$NamespaceName = "redacted",
[bool]$NoWait = $false,
[bool]$RequiresDuplicateDetection = $false,
[string]$ResourceGroupName,
[string]$Status = "Active",
[string]$SubscriptionId,
[bool]$SupportOrdering = $true,
$AzureResourceGroupName = "redacted",
$subId = "redacted"
    
Update-ServiceBusTopic -AsJob $AsJob -AutoDeleteOnIdle $AutoDeleteOnIdle -DefaultMessageTimeToLive $DefaultMessageTimeToLive -DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow $DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow -EnableBatchedOperations $EnableBatchedOperations -EnableExpress $EnableExpress -EnablePartitioning $EnablePartitioning -MaxSizeInMegabytes $MaxSizeInMegabytes -TopicName $TopicName -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -NoWait $NoWait -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroupName -Status $Status -SubscriptionId $subId -SupportOrdering $SupportOrdering
```

I then get the error of

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-EnableBatchedOperations'
```

Comment: I can’t test right now, but it looks like the problem is in your call to ```Set-AzServiceBusTopic``` - instead of ```… $EnableBatchedOperationsValue``` try ```… -EnableBatchedOperations:$EnableBatchedOperations …```. You’re currently trying to make the literal string value ```”-EnableBatchedOperations”``` in ```$EnableBatchedOperationsValue``` act like it’s a switch parameter, but Powershell is treating it like a string, which it can’t bind to a parameter. As an aside, you might find “splatting” a hashtable into ```Set-AzAerviceBusTopic``` is easier to maintain if you have lots of parameters…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proxying "conditional" parameter arguments, you'll want to build a [splatting table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3):

```
function Update-ServiceBusTopic {
    param (
        [bool]$AsJob,
        [int]$AutoDeleteOnIdle,
        [int]$DefaultMessageTimeToLive,
        [int]$DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow,
        [bool]$EnableBatchedOperations,
        [bool]$EnableExpress,
        [bool]$EnablePartitioning,
        [int]$MaxSizeInMegabytes,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$TopicName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$NamespaceName,
        [bool]$NoWait,
        [string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [string]$Status,
        [string]$SubscriptionId,
        [bool]$SupportOrdering
    )

    # create hashtable for the conditionally forwarded parameters
    $additionalParams = @{}
    foreach ($paramName in 'EnableBatchedOperations', 'EnableExpress', 'EnablePartitioning', 'SupportOrdering') {
        # If the user supplied any input for any of the parameters, copy it to the table we created above
        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($paramName)) {
            $additionalParams[$paramName] = $PSBoundParameters[$paramName]
        }
    }

    # ...

    try {
        # then pass the conditional parameters to the target command with the @ splatting operator
        Set-AzServiceBusTopic @additionalParams -TopicName $TopicName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -AutoDeleteOnIdle (New-TimeSpan -Minutes $AutoDeleteOnIdle) -DefaultMessageTimeToLive (New-TimeSpan -Days $DefaultMessageTimeToLive) -DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow (New-TimeSpan -Minutes $DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow)
    }
    # ...
```